# Spring MVC: @SessionAttributes shared among controllers?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an abstract controller support class for searches and result lists:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("query")
public abstract class SearchController<Q extends SearchQuery> {
    @RequestMapping
    public String performSearch(@ModelAttribute("query") Q query) {
        ....
    }

    @ModelAttribute("query")
    public abstract Q createDefaultSearchQuery();
}
```

Several actual search controllers extend this base class.

After having accessed one of the controllers (say `/searchBooks.html` using `BookSearchQuery implements SearchQuery`) the query is correctly stored in the session, available for subsequent requests.

However, when I access another controller (say `/searchAuthors.html` using `AuthorSearchQuery implements SearchQuery`) the query from the last request (`BookSearchQuery`) is still being used for the new controller causing a `ClassCastException` later on.

I have tried moving the `@SessionAttribute` annotation from the support class to the implementation classes, to no avail.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is this by design? What can I do?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `@SessionAttributes` this objects will be stored in your HttpSession with the same name and they will be accessible (shared) from different controllers. So, Spring is acting correctly.

I think the best approach in your scenario is rename this attribute in every subclass ("BookQuery", "AutorQuery", ...). Not very elegant at all :(

Comment: I had hoped Spring would somehow qualify the name of the attribute in the session context with the controller name. I can't rename the attribute name because I'm using the model bean name ("query") in the methods of the abstract controller. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, no ideas, and I think what you want is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

I just tried this on Spring 3.0.2 and the session attributes are not shared between controllers.  In fact I was looking for the opposite effect and that's how I found out.